# Unable to Affect Scintilla Control Programmatically at Runtime

Tags: c#, .net, scintilla

I'm attempting to use the [ScintillaNET control](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/) in an application I am working on.  I drag and drop the control into my form and run form. The control appears on the form.  This is good.  In addition, if I set any of the properties in the control's properties editor (ConfigurationManager.Language, for example), I am able to type in that language and see syntax highlighting occur.

Where I run into problems is when I attempt to change properties programmatically.  For example, I attempt to load text from a file into the form (I'm doing this in the form's Load).  The text doesn't display.  I also can't seem to show the line numbers or do any other number of tasks (including programmatically change the Language).

Any idea what I may be doing wrong?  Even something as simple as the code below doesn't seem to work:

```
private void scintilla1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    scintilla1.ConfigurationManager.Language = "xml";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some time playing around with the different events, it appears that I cannot affect the Scintilla control until after it is already visible.  Hence, the "Load" event does not let me make any programmatic changes to the control until I've set it visible.

It's a little strange, and seems sort of pointless to me to have the Load event at all, but I just wanted to let everybody know what is happening in case someone else ran into the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `scintilla1.ConfigurationManager.Configure();`

```
private void scintilla1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    scintilla1.ConfigurationManager.Language = "xml";
    scintilla1.ConfigurationManager.Configure();
}
```

Comment: It's been awhile since I worked on this project, but thanks for the response. I hope it can help someone else out.